# How to tell onet.xml dont verify <navbarlink>?

Tags: publishing, navigation

I have some navbarlinks in the onet.xml. However, creation or provision of those publishing pages (aspx that have link in the navbar) happens much later when provision a site. Is there a way to tell onet.xml not to verify the nav bar? These navbarlink shows up (on the provisioned web) but all the way to the bottom (just b/c they are publishing page, not sure). Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend populating stuff like this in a Feature and have it activated as part of the ONET, rather than trying to provision this stuff within ONET itself. Far easier to manage, easier to update, more portable, and just generally nicer all round.

Here's a link with quite a fair bit of info around doing the navigation within a Feature:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42401/NavBars-If-only-it-was-that-simple.aspx?display=Print